# Insert a vector to a database?

Tags: c++

How can I insert a vector into a mysql database?

```
database->queryDatabase("INSERT INTO recordings (title, recording, kit, date) VALUES ('"+recordingTitle+"', '"+ recordingArray +"', '"+kitID+"', '"+recordingDateTime.toString()+"')");
```

This gives an error:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' in 'operator+(const QString&, const char*)(((const char*)"\', \'")) + ((Studio*)this)->Studio::recordingArray'
```

Do I need to convert the vector to a String before inserting it? Or can I store a vector in a mysql db?

Comment: Please google SQL injection before you go any further.

Comment: SQL injection is of no worry for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What are the data types of everything involved here?

Comment: everything works apart from recordingArray which is: std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> > recordingArray;

Comment: Regardless of SQL injection, prepared statements are the way to go, unless your 100% sure that your strings will never, ever contain anything that could screw up the SQL.

Comment: You need to turn that into a string then. standard containers don't make any assumptions about how to do that for you.

Comment: @Mat it will never contain anything that will screw up the sql

Comment: @Matthew 'Cogwheel' Orlando is there no way to store a vector in a database?

Comment: Some databases support some forms of that, but not all and I believe you'll need special syntax/extensions, so you'll need specific code to do it. The normal way of storing arrays is as separate rows in a table (usually with a foreign key to another table).

Comment: Not unless the interface you use to interact with your database accepts a vector object. The thing you're doing above is making a string. If you want to do it that way, you need to write code to turn your vector into a string.